# Vue add multiple events

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

I am using `vue-draggable` to drag some elements to `div1` and `div2`. Draggable event `:move` is only true when the **teamName1** is greater than 1. If the **teamname1** is greater than 1 it can be dragged on to div1 as well as to div2, which is basically wrong. Is there a way to add `:move:checkMove2` such as `:move:checkMove1` so that draggable event `:move="checkMove2"` gets true for **second div** when teamName2 value > 1? I tried to use `:move="checkMove1 && checkMove2"` but it did not help.

```html
<!-- Div 1 :move="checkMove1" where the draggable is true if teamName1 is greater than 1 -->

<div>
<b-form-input id="input-small" size="md" v-model="teamName1"></b-form-input>
</div>

<!-- Is there a way to add :move="checkMove2" to the below div '2' as well, where the draggable will
 be true if teamName2 is greater than 1 ?? -->

<div>
<b-form-input id="input-small" size="md" v-model="teamName2"></b-form-input>
</div>

<draggable :list="text.people" class="list-group" draggable=".item" group="a" :move="checkMove1" @add="person">
  <div class="list-group-item item" v-for="element in text.people" :key="element.name">
    <p>{{element.first_name}}</p>
  </div>
</draggable>
```

**Data**

```
teamName1: '',
teamName2: ''
```

**Methods**

```js
checkMove1(evt){
  if(this.teamName1.length < 1){
    return false;
   }
 },

checkMove2(evt){
  if(this.teamName2.length < 1){
     return false
  }
},
```

Comment: Why not just make a new method that has `return this.checkMove1(evt) && this.checkMove2(evt)`?

Comment: @Phil if i use && in that scenario. It will only get true when both teamname1 and teamname2 consists of value. But it should enable checkMove1 when teamName1 has a value and checkMove2 to be enabled when teamName2 consists of a value. If both teamName1 and teamName2 has a value then it's suppose to enable checkMove1 and checkMove2.